# Is there a jquery plugin that you can use to gray out an image and add another image partially over the grayed out one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a page where I need a way for when the user mouses over an image, it grays out and a shows a gear icon over that image.  If there's no way for the image to gray out, then is there a way just to overlay the gear icon on the top-right corner of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a grayscale effect in all modern browser (i think only IE supports that). Another method is to use two images and on hover the gray image will show up. Something like [this](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/greyscale-hover-effect-w-css-jquery/).

You can use an jquery [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) effect for showing a div that has an absolute position over the img.

Something like:

```
$("#YOURIMGID").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).next("#GEARID").show());
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).next("#GEARID").hide());
  }
);
```

You html would be something like:

```
<div style='position:relative;'>
<img src='image.jpg' alt='' id='YOURIMGID' />
<div style='position:absolute;display:none;' id='GEARID'><img src='gear.png' alt='gear'/></div> 
</div>
```

ps. don't copy my code, better use of css and html would be nice ;-), this is just too give you an impression.

Comment: You could substitute `$(this).next("#GEARID")` with just `$("#GEARID")` if the ID of the Gear element is unique.

Comment: true and in this case it's probably better to use classes (for the validation of the (x)html).